# Passing data into a third view with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a app that im writing. The first page is a list of books, when you click on a book it takes you to the chapter selection of that book, which works. However i have an issue when i try to select a chapter and go to it. From what i can tell it looks like my route is not valid according to the .state() function.

In my chapter selection template i have the following

```
<ion-view view-title="{{textbook.title}}">
 <ion-content>
  <ion-list>
   <ion-item ng-repeat="chapter in textbook.chapters">
    <a ng-href="#/app/textbooks/{{textbook.id}}/ch/{{chapter.id}}">{{chapter.title}}</a>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

In my app.js i have the following routes.

This is the chapter select

```
.state('app.chapters', {
 url: "/textbooks/:textbookId",
 views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/textbook-chapters.html",
    controller: 'TextbookSectionCtrl'
  }
 }
})
```

This should be the individual chapter

```
.state('app.chapter', {
  url: "/textbooks/:textbookId/ch/:chapterId",
  views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/textbook-chapter.html",
    controller: 'TextbookChapterCtrl'
  }
 }
});
```

You can download the directory zip here
https://www.sendspace.com/file/4iiuy2

Comment: Looks like there is no need for "/app" in 'app.chapter'. There also is a typo in textbook-chapters.html in the link: "textbook" vs "textbooks"

Comment: Even with the correction there is still issues with it navigating me back to the main page and not going through to the template

Comment: Look at the console log - there also is a problem with the controller, which is outside the scope of this question.